# tinkerboard android - /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, arm, temperature

I am using a tinkerboard with an android + chroot linux. When I try to read temperature by the following command:

```
cat  /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp
```

I get the following error :

```
cat: /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp: No such file or directory
```

If I run the tinkerboard directly with a linux distribution rather than android I am able to read the temperature by the above command.

The tinkerboard uses the RK3288 cpu which has a TS-ADC [temperature sensor.](http://www.boardcon.com/download/Rockchip-RK3288-datasheet-V1.0.pdf)

Any suggestions?

```
lsmod - linux:
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   94208  3
snd_soc_hdmi_codec     16384  1
mali_kbase            335872  0
dw_hdmi_i2s_audio      16384  0
rk_crypto              24576  0
dw_wdt                 16384  0
syscon_reboot_mode     16384  0
reboot_mode            16384  1 syscon_reboot_mode
r8723bs               544768  0
zram                   20480  5
ip_tables              20480  0
autofs4                28672  0
```

lsmod - android ( linux chroot ):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
```

Comment: What is your kernel version on both platforms? What is the output of `lsmod` on both platforms? I guess your android doesn't have the drivers for temperature sensors.

Comment: I am not sure about the kernel versions exactly but both are officially supported distros by tinkerboard. How can I install the drivers?

Comment: You can query the kernel version using `uname -a`. Maybe try `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp0_input` or similar inside `/sys/class/hwmon` path on android? Maybe try `thermal_zone0` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

After some research by my colleague:
The kernel was missing the required drivers. Fortunately the newest updates to the kernel included the thermal sensor. It now works.